# Assigning value of variable through pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Why the output of x in the programming is 0 instead of 1/2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
        double *xp,x;
        xp = &x;
        *xp = 1/2;
        printf("%f\n",x);
        return 0;
}
```

give the result of

```
0.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `1/2` is `0`. On the other hand, `1.0/2.0` is `0.5`. The rule is, if both operands are integral, the division is integral as well. It then gets assigned to a float storage, and then gets printed as a float; but by that time, it's too late.

Nothing to do with pointers, really.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are dividing two integers.

```
1/2;
```

The result of 1 / 2 is an integer result, zero.  To correct this:

```
1.0 / 2.0;
```

This will return a floating point result.